# Clenshaw-Curtis integration without Fourier

Tags: na.numerical-analysis, orthogonal-polynomials, quadrature

The [Clenshaw-Curtis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clenshaw%E2%80%93Curtis_quadrature) quadrature rule approximates an integral $I=\int\limits_{-1}^{1} f(x) \, dx$ by $$I\approx I_n = \sum\limits_{j=1}^N f(x_j)w_j \, ,$$
where the $x_j$'s are the roots of the $N$-th order Chebyshev polynomial, and  and $w_j$'s their respective weight. To prove the accuracy of this integration formula, one usually goes by either Fourier representation of $f(x)=f(\cos (\theta))$, or by the "Fourier" expansion of $f$ in the Chebyshev polynomials. See e.g., in the Wiki page.

**My Question:** Is there a way to prove the accuracy of this formula, which does not rely on spectral/Fourier theory? Specifically, to show that it is exact ($I=I_n$) for polynomials of degree $\leq n$, and to bound its error for $f\in C^n$.

Answer (score 2):

In ["Error bounds for the Clenshaw-Curtis quadrature formulas"](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/BF01931811) the error bounds are obtained without relying on analytic function theory (and no Fourier transforms).